# How do I secure a REST API from CSRF when both frontend and API are on the same Go server?

Tags: rest, go, csrf-protection, gorilla

I am working on a web site created in Go.

It is possible to access it both via web (server side pages generated via golang templates) and a REST API (for external users who whant to integrate their own software). The Go server handles both types of requests, with a subrouter that handles the API when calls are sent to the subpath "my-url-root/api".

- The web pages use secure cookies
- The API is stateless: no cookies (each API method must receive in the
  header an authentication token obtained via a dedicated login method)

I successfully applied gorilla/csrf to protect the web pages from csrf attacks, but that modification (essential before I go live) is now creating an issue with the API.

**My question**
When the CSRF is implemented, all GET requests sent to the api URLs work as expected, but any other request sent (e.g. a POST to a method to add something via my REST api) generates an html response that typically states "forbidden - invalid csrf token".

Is there a straightforward way that I am missing? I searched for answers but none applicable to the case where the api is served by the same server and most of all it is stateless.
Should I see if I can "disable" the gorilla csrf protection for the subrouter (though I do not even know if that is possible and if that is even safe...)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your api is actually stateless, I don't think it needs `csrf` protection.. No cookies `===` No csrf. You can have 2 routers, Mount one at `/` ( use the csrf middleware here) and the other at `/api` ( without the crsf middleware )

Comment: @adelowo thanks! I tried as soon as you suggested it was possible and how. I created a SubMux and I used it to handle "/" and "/*" paths (by using the gorilla csrf middleware), then I created another SubMux to handle "/api" and "/api/*" paths without csrf.

I then made many tests with browser and soapui calls to check all combinations and it worked!

Comment: Should I update my question with examples of my code to help the community? In particular I was surprised it worked because I thought that by applying the CSRF middleware to the root "/*" then it would have been applied even to all descending paths... and indeed all web pages like "/users", "/orgs" have the csrf active (they are all handled via SubMuxes assigned to the SubMux I created for the URL "/*").

I suppose that it works because I created the SubMux for the URLs "/api/*" assigning it to the "very first mux" and not to the SubMux I created for the root "/*"? I am using goji...

Comment: @Romano add the solution as an answer.

Comment: What is order of your route definition?

Comment: @Romano yes, that is correct

Comment: @kosa Well, I was surprised because by looking at the order of my route definition I started with the root and THEN I added the one for the API. But now, as confirmed by adelow here above, I understand that the order does not matter. What matters is which router I assigned the subrouter to. I am far from my pc now but in a couple of days I will add samples of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I tried to apply the suggestions above and I came up with a solution to my problem.

I tested that it works by checking web and api calls against my urls and sub-urls with and without the csrf protection.

Just a clarification to my previous comment. To be more precise the order I created the Submuxes did not matter but of course I had then followed a proper order when I wrote down the lines to Handle each path.

So, the order IS important.

This is what I did (just bits of code).

I used goji as a router and gorilla/csrf for the csrf protection.

NOTE: I did not include all my code but just the most important parts to describe what I did.

1) I created a mux using

```
mux := goji.NewMux()
```

2) since my APIs are served under the url "/api" and related sub urls, I created a Submux for the api

```
apiMux := goji.SubMux()
```

3) I assigned the pages that match the path "/api" and "/api*" to this subMux

Note that I did NOT include any csrf protection

```
mux.Handle(pat.New("/api/*"), apiMux)

mux.Handle(pat.New("/api"), apiMux)
```

4) I created a Submux for web pages of my site

```
webMux := goji.SubMux()
```

5) I assigned the pages that match the path "/" and "/*" to this subMux

Note that here in my code I linked the middleware for the csrf protection

```
mux.Handle(pat.New("/"), csrf.Protect(csrfKey, csrf.Secure(true))(webMux))
mux.Handle(pat.New("/*"), csrf.Protect(csrfKey, csrf.Secure(true))(webMux))
```

6) For my benefit, I created other SubMuxes to handle other paths, like "/users", "/users/1", "/users/addform".
This step is important: I assigned this "userMux" to the webMux, and not to the main mux created at step 1.

In this way, the csrf protection is inherited. Example:

```
usersMux := goji.SubMux()

webMux.Handle(pat.New("/users/*"), usersMux)

webMux.Handle(pat.New("/users"), usersMux)
```

IN few words, this was the solution to my problem:

I) I assigned this "apiMux" to the main mux created at step 1.

I did not assigned it to any other mux. I did NOT assigned it to the webMux that handles the root url "/" and "/*"

II) The order is important, so I implemented the code for the API urls and then the code for the web urls

I hope it helps. And most of all I hope the explanation was clear... (if not just let me know).
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction